# Key combination without modifier keys

Tags: c#

I need to get key combinations like "A" & "B" , "S" & "D" & "F" like that in C#.
I can implement key combinations using modifier keys,like Control, Alter.
But here, I need the key combinations without using those modifier keys.

Comment: ...write some code....

Answer (score 1):

You will need to register for the KeyDown and the KeyUp events and keep track off which keys are currently down yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to P/Invoke `GetKeyState`. I'm guessing you're dealing with either a WinForms app or a WPF app, but in either case what you can do is in your KeyPressed event call the GetKeyState method and poll the keys you're interested in to see if those are pressed as well. Here's a helpful implementation of GetKeyState:

http://sanity-free.org/17/obtaining_key_state_info_in_dotnet_csharp_getkeystate_implementation.html